# Posting data to SFDC via rest API

Tags: rest-api, apexrest

I'm learning basics of using Rest API and using workbench to explore it .

As of now , I'm correctly able to make get Call to salesforce for e.g

```
/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Account/001K00000XXXXX
```

is bringing me details of the record mentioned above

Now I'm **testing POST via Rest API To SFDC**. This is the area where I'm having problems and doubts.

**My first question.**

as I'm trying to create Account record via post request , is there a standard similar way, like above(which is GEt request to retrieve data)  to create record and get ID back via POST ?

I tried hard to search but what I got are Salesforce articles is : this can be done by creating your own rest resource(Custom class exposed as Rest Resource like in this way

```
@RestResource(URLMapping = '/SingleAccounInsert/*')

 Global class CreateSingleAccount {

 @httpPost
  Global static string  CreateAcc( string nm, string Descrip, String Type, String area){
  Account acc = new Account();
  acc.name = nm ;
  acc.Description = Descrip;
  acc.Type = Type;
  acc.Area__c= area;
  insert acc ;
  return acc.Id;
 } }
```

**Second question :**

Even If try to use above rest resource and post following 
data to SFDC   on URL  :

> /services/apexrest/SingleAccounInsert/

```
    {
  "name" : "Sansui Corp",
  "description" : "Electronics Buys",
  "Type" : "XYZ",
  "Area__c" : "USA"
}
```

I Get below JSON PARSER ERROR

> message: Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: name
>   at [line:2, column:13] errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

I'm stuck now, not sure how to test POST Requests.

Articles referred :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_rest_2.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_rest_1.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is standard way to create any record in Salesforce via POST

```
/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/OBJECTNAME/
```

replace OBJECTNAME with object name for which you want to insert the record.

for example Account record can be created as follows

[image]

If you want to update account you need to  pass Account id in url and select **PATCH** as method type

```
/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/ACCOUNT/RECORDID
```

JSON in body

```
{

"NAME":"Erase item"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks , this actually works But have one question. If Suppose I've to update same account, should I've to use PATCH as POST is not working and getting following error : METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
errorCode: METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED message: HTTP Method 'POST' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET,PATCH,DELETE.  I tried to use PATCH also, through update is happening, but getting 204 as response

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 6):

You can use standard REST API as showed by above answer .Also i would like to point out mistake you are doing in the custom REST API

The JSON parameters that you send should match the parmeters of the @HTTP POST function of apex .Hence your proper JSON as per function you have written would be as below

```
 {
 "nm" : "Sansui Corp",
 "Descrip" : "Electronics Buys",
  "Type" : "XYZ",
 "area" : "USA"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith for pointing out this mistake!! I could only mark only as answer so for now,  could only give + 1 to your answer .